# Reference for some lines of typical khutbah

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for the arabic version(with punctuation i.e. kasrah dhummah etc) of the following lines which are used in typical khutbah. Upon google searching this transliteration I could not find it. Also where is it taken from?

> Fainna khairal hadeethi kitabullah, wa khairal hadi, hadi Muhammad (saw), wa sharrul umur muhdathatuha, wa kullu bida’atin dalaala, wa kullu dalalatin finnar

For example I have seen this [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=xQdhz5Oi-5gC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=Fainna%20khairal&source=bl&ots=teOFfNSWGe&sig=ACfU3U2yK9Y5sN5_a-3ZIaRx93UgFMMZuw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi85I_49YbgAhXLC-wKHbbzABs4ChDoATACegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=Fainna%20khairal&f=false) and [here](http://www.irfi.org/articles3/articles_4701_4800/how%20to%20give%20khutbashtml.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from a sermon given by the Prophet and has been recorded by various hadith compilers including in [Sahih Muslim - **كتاب الجمعة** , **باب تخفيف الصلاة والخطبة**](https://archive.org/stream/SahihMuslimarabic-English7VolumesPublishedByDarussalam/SahihMuslimVol.2-ahadith1161-2262#page/n385/mode/2up):

[image]

The last part in your quote وكل ضلالة في النار   has been recorded by [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai/19/23) etc.

Comment: I don't recognize a lot of those diacritics, e.g. the last one onوَخَيْر (end of the second line) looks like a fatha combined with a damma. There's similar combinations on the third line. Is this a printing error, or just a different way of writing that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @goldPseudo I am not familiar with this style either. I think it indicates alternate diacritics, i.e. it exists with both either a fatha or a damma. See [here](https://archive.org/stream/FP144371/03_144373#page/n26/mode/2up) and [here](https://archive.org/details/waq105914/page/n566).